# Why does my Twig for loop not get a Key?

Tags: matrix

I'm looping through a Matrix field called Documents. The matrix has three fields:

- Document (an asset field)
- Document Title (plain text field)
- Document Type (a category field)

I need to loop through the matrix and output all the rows, but grouped by Document Type. This seems like it should work:

```
{% set grouped = entry.documents | group('documentType.title') %}

{% for categoryTitle, groupedRows in grouped %}
    TITLE HERE: {{ categoryTitle }}

    {% for document in groupedRows %}
        <br/>{{ document.documentTitle }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is that `{{ categoryTitle }}` is blank. Nothing in it. The code runs, but the key is blank. The grouped rows are populated.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `documentType` in your group filter returns a criteria model prepared to query for categories related to that Matrix block. Use the `first()` method to try and get the first element matching your criteria and you can now access a property like the category’s title.

```
{% set grouped = entry.documents|group('documentType.first().title') %}
```

But this is also dangerous, as it might happen that a Matrix block does not have a category assigned (may be that this category got deleted). Here’s how you could improve it and write the code a bit more defensively.

```
{% set grouped = entry.documents|group('{ documentType.first() ? documentType.first().title : 'No categories }') %}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you'd like `{{ categoryTitle }}` to be the current groups `documentType.title`?

If so, I would output `document.documentType` for the first document in each group using `{% if loop.first %}`.

Complete code suggestion would be:

```
{% set grouped = entry.documents|group('documentType.first().title') %}

{% for groupedRows in grouped %}
  {% for document in groupedRows %}
    {% if loop.first %}
      {{ document.documentType }}
    {% endif %}
    {{ document.documentTitle }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**EDIT:** updated to use [carlcs](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/15712/4466) group filter suggestion.